# Php page redirecton

Tags: php, html

I have been browsing a good couple hours regarding php page redirection. It should be quite straight forward task. However, I am unable to understand what is going on...

I have tried the following two lines of code.

```
header('Location: http://www.google.ca');
```

It works!

```
header('Location: localFile.php');
```

It does not work!

```
//redirect.php
<?php
    header('Location: localFile.php');
?>

//localFile.php
<?php
    echo "good!";
?>
```

My public_html directory contains localFile.php and redirect.php. I don't think that my code is wrong!! Hope someone can tell me what is going on...

Comment: *How* does it not work? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? What actually happens?

Comment: Try putting a leading forward slash: header('Location: /localFile.php');

Comment: Get rid of `//redirect.php`.  No output is allowed and there is a newline there.

Comment: The browser displays "header('Location: localFile.php');" :-(

Comment: I also changed the localFile.php content to <?php phpinfo(); ?> instead of echo...

Comment: If the browser is showing your PHP source code, then you're not using an HTTP server that executes PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) though I'm not totally convinced because you said the remote redirect works

Answer (score 0):

A location in the headers refers to the URL and not to files. If the file you want to redirect to is in the root, add a forward slash:

```
header('Location: /localFile.php');
```

Your first attempt with https://google.ca worked because it refers to an actual URL

Comment: OP says the files are in the same directory so a relative location should work fine